# PHP - удалить из строки HEX c2a00a

Tags: php

Есть результат вывода строки через функцию bin2hex :

> 0a0ac2a00a  Кирпич полнотелый 6%   К-1,0   250*120*65 
>   0,320/3208,809,80
>
> 0a0a  Кирпич полнотелый 6%   К-1,4   250*120*88 
>   0,345/25610800/14,5811800/15,93
>
> 0a0aКирпич полнотелый 12%   К-1,0   250*120*65    0,320/3208,409,40

Строки в которых есть '0a0ac2a00a' и '0a0a ' - выводятся с каким то пробелом в начале строки на странице в кодировке utf-8.
Не могу понять что это за hex-символы и как их удалить.
Стандартными функциями, regex - пока результата не добился.

Вот код, который выводит результат:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile('Sample_11_ReadWord2007.html');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$lenght_max = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->length;

function replaceSpecial($str){
$chunked = str_split($str,1);
$str = ""; 
foreach($chunked as $chunk){
    $num = ord($chunk);
    // Remove non-ascii & non html characters
    if ($num >= 32 && $num <= 123){
            $str.=$chunk;
    }
}   
return $str;
} 
  for ($i=0; $i<$lenght_max; $i++) {
    //get all rows from the table
  $rows = $tables->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 
  foreach ($rows as $row) 
  { 
      $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

      if (!preg_match('/кирпич/i',$cols->item(0)->nodeValue )){
   // echo the values 
      $str = $cols->item(0)->nodeValue;
      echo bin2hex($str);
      //echo replaceSpecial($str);
      echo ltrim ($cols->item(1)->nodeValue); 
      echo trim($cols->item(2)->nodeValue);
      echo trim($cols->item(3)->nodeValue);
      echo trim(preg_replace( '/[^0-9,.\s\/]/', '', $cols->item(4)->nodeValue ));
      echo trim(preg_replace( '/[^0-9,.\s\/]/', '', $cols->item(5)->nodeValue )).'</br>';
      }
    }  

 }
```

Ссылка на файл [html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/150Fg2ZHFnd-Fy1PXCd9x3BjKOtbeCD1P/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: случаем utf-8 with bom? Тогда понятен символ в начале.

Comment: нет исходный файл в кодировке UTF-8 без bom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Касаемо пробелов перед "кирпичами" это были 0xc2a0 (&npsp - No Break Space),  а остальные 0d0a202020 это банальные  \r\n (0x0D 0x0A ) и пробел  (0x20).

Решение - замените

```
echo ltrim($cols->item(1)->nodeValue);
```

на

```
echo preg_replace('/\xc2\xa0/','',ltrim($cols->item(1)->nodeValue));
```

Comment: добавил код выше в вопрос

Comment: Добавил https://drive.google.com/file/d/150Fg2ZHFnd-Fy1PXCd9x3BjKOtbeCD1P/view?usp=sharing